# Running Hadoop in standalone mode on Windows

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

What I understand from running Hadoop or Map reduce jobs on standalone mode is that we don't require any Hadoop daemons to be running. Everything is on the JVM.

So here is the problem.

1. I want to run a simple word count map reduce job on my machine (client machine), which is on Windows.
2. I have done the coding of word count in an IDE (eclipse), so I want to run it from eclipse.

How can this be achieved?

Do I need to use some plugin like the (`Karmasphere` plugin) or can it be done without using any plugins?

I am able to run the above in Linux. I am using the Cloudera provided VM. Here I created the same project in eclipse.
In the driver code I added the below line and finally ran it as Java application

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "local");
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","file:///");

Job job = new Job(conf);
```

While configuring for running the Java application, I provided input file and output folder name as the program arguments and it ran.

But doing same in windows was no good.

Comment: Try this http://lintool.github.io/Cloud9/docs/content/start-standalone.html. For more information on standalone mode, look here http://arifn.web.id/blog/2011/02/16/quickly-switching-hadoop-mode.html

Comment: Do you want to connect hadoop from eclipse which is on windows machine ?

Comment: yes, but by connecting do u mean hadoop to be installed somewhere. I am of the impression that i don't need to install hadoop anywhere for making things running in standalone mode.
Putting all in simple words - I understand that in order to run a map reduce job on hadoop as standalone mode, all i need to do is to write a program in eclipse, import all the required jars and run my application as java application.
AM I correct?